# Start and End indices of the matched strings after comparison

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to create two lists containing the 'start' and 'end' indices of a string.
In this case, two strings are of equal lengths.
For example

```
str1='ATGGATCGATCG'
str2='CGGGCGCGCGCG'
```

Here, matched lengths are: GG, CG, CG
I want the following kind of outputs:

```
list = [2,3,6,7,10,11] #list of the matched indices
start = [2,6,10] #start indices of the matched lengths
end = [3,7,11] #end indices if the matched lengths
```

Now, my chunk of codes looks like the following one but I want the indices to locate the matched sequences.

```
str1='ATGGATCGATCG'
str2='CGGGCGCGCGCG'

result1 = ''
result2 = ''

#handle the case where one string is longer than the other
maxlen=len(str2) if len(str1)<len(str2) else len(str1)

#loop through the characters
for i in range(maxlen): 
    letter1=str1[i:i+1]
    letter2=str2[i:i+1]
    if ((letter1 == letter2) and letter1 in ['A','T','C','G'] and letter2 in ['A','T','C','G']):
        result1+=letter1
        result2+=letter2
```

Comment: Do you want string matches of any length? Or are you looking for length 2 matches?

Comment: Are your matches always going to be in pairs? For example if your strings are `'AAAB'` and `AAAC`. What is your desired list of indices `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 3]` ?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri [1, 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is practically crying out for `zip`:

```
str1='ATGGATCGATCG'
str2='CGGGCGCGCGCG'

matches = []
for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(str1,str2)):
    if a == b:
        if not matches or matches[-1][1] != i-1
            matches.append([i,i])
        else:
            matches[-1][1] += 1

print(matches)
starts = [k[0] for k in matches]
ends   = [k[1] for k in matches]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3], [6, 7], [10, 11]]
```

This will also capture single character matches.  You can filter those out in a quick loop after, if need be.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `numpy.split` to split on nonconsecutive indices and get your desired outcome in two lines:

```
lst = [i for i, (s1,s2) in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)) if s1==s2]
start, end = zip(*[(arr[0], arr[-1]) for arr in np.split(lst, np.where(np.diff(lst) != 1)[0] + 1)])
```

Output:

```
((2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something similar w/regex.

```
import re
str1='ATGGATCGATCG'
str2='CGGGCGCGCGCG'

pat = 'GG|CG|CG'

matches = [[(m.span()[0],m.span()[1]-1) for m in re.finditer(pat,x)] for x in [str1,str2]]

m = set(matches[0]) & set(matches[1])
starts= [x[0] for x in m]
ends= [x[1] for x in m]

print(m,starts,ends, sep='\n')
```

Output

```
{(2, 3), (6, 7), (10, 11)}
[2, 6, 10]
[3, 7, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few corrections to your code 1) `max()` is a built-in, no need to do an if statement, 2) strings are already list type objects, hence `"a" in "bbbbabb"` already returns True, no need to put each letter in a list.

It appears you need a function for determining how much the start of two strings agree by.

```
import itertools as it
def f(s,t): 
    return sum(it.takewhile(bool,map(lambda z:z[0]==z[1],zip(s,t))))
```

With such a function, we can now do as you describe and find all simultaneous matches of any length between strings:

```
str1='ATGGATCGATCG'
str2='CGGGCGCGCGCG'

matches = [(i,i+l-1) for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(str1,str2)) if (l:=f(str1[i:],str2[i:]))>=2]
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a helper function that will calculate length of common prefix of two strings at given index

```
def helper(index, str1, str2):
    length = 0
    try:
        while str1[index] == str2[index]: #and other needed conditions
            length += 1
            index += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return length
```

Now we want to use it while iterating over

```
index = 0
result = []
while index < min(len(str1), len(str2)):
    length = helper(index, str1, str2)
    if length > 0:
        result.append(i, i+length)
        i += length + 1 # We can omit one character as it was checked in helper
    else:
        i += 1
```